# Windows Phone 7 dialog input box

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, input, dialog, popup

I have been surfing the web and MSDN for the equivalent java method JOptionPane.showInputDialog() for Windows Phone 7 but cannot find one. I simply want an input dialog box to appear if the user has achieved a high score, so that the user may enter their name.

Thanks!
    CodeKingPlusPlus

Comment: Just create your own UserControl

Comment: How would I do that? I am not familiar with C#, .NET, wp7 ect... Could you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you might want to check out the [Coding4Fun toolkit](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/) for Windows Phone 7. Included in the toolkit is a InputPrompt control, which is exactly what you need in this case. It's also free.

If you need help getting started check out [this article](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Coding4Fun-Toolkit-for-WP7-Overview-and-Getting-Started) which contains an overview on all the controls included in the toolkit.

Comment: The Coding4Fun toolkit just crashed visual studio. I added the references and declared the namespaces in the xaml code....

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus I just tried it right now by right clicking on the References folder and installing it via Nuget and it worked perfectly. What version of VS are you using?

Comment: 2010 ultimate. What is Nuget? I tried it all manually by adding the references, and adding the namespaces at the top of the xaml code...

Comment: Check out nuget.org . Basically most open source libraries, including Coding4Fun, have there libraries hosted on Nuget. When you install Nuget you can browse these libraries and have them directly added inside your project instead of doing it manually. It also makes sure that your project is compatible.

Comment: Thanks! I got it working. However I cannot figure out how to use it. I read the documentation on Coding4fun and windowsphonegeek. And they both were unhelpful to me. Could you answer a few specific questions like:                                                     Where do I declare the InputPrompt? (all my other GUI elements I created in xaml) How do I make the InputPrompt invisible until a certain event occurs? How do I use the input_Completed event handler? (it wouldnt recognize it for me?) I think the rest should be fairly straight forward such as getting the value entered by the user...